# alpinejs @mouseover not working correctly

Tags: laravel, alpine.js

I want to trigger a dropdown menu via hover so use @mouseover. But when the cursor places between text and chevron, dropdown becomes hide. I use mouseover with a tag so it should contain text and chevron, shouldn't it?

[image]

here's my code

```php
<header class="relative z-50" x-data="{ dropdown: '' }">
    <nav class="overflow-hidden z-50">
        <div class="container space-x-14 py-7 desktop:justify-start flex items-center z-50">
            <nav class="space-x-14">
                <a @mouseover="dropdown = dropdown === 'open' ? '' : 'open'" class="cursor-pointer font-semibold">
                    <span class="border-b-2 pb-2 transition duration-300" :class="dropdown === 'open' ? 'border-seaweed' : 'border-transparent'">{{ __('test1') }}</span> <span class="inline-block bg-caret-down bg-center bg-no-repeat w-4 h-2"></span>
                </a>
```

what is the prolem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, we need to embed the two `<span>` elements into a `<div>` where we add the [`pointer-events-none`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/pointer-events) class (assuming you are using TailwindCSS) to disable the pointer events of the child elements. Furthermore we also add the `@mouseleave` event to change the open state.

```
<a @mouseover="dropdown = 'open'"
   @mouseleave="dropdown = ''" 
   class="cursor-pointer font-semibold">
    <div class="pointer-events-none">
      <span class="border-b-2 pb-2 transition duration-300" :class="dropdown === 'open' ? 'border-seaweed' : 'border-transparent'">{{ __('test1') }}</span>
      <span class="inline-block bg-caret-down bg-center bg-no-repeat w-4 h-2"></span>
    <div>
</a>
```